# How to access etcd cluster endpoints from kubernetes master

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

Is there a way that I can access the `etcd` endpoints from `kubernetes` master node without actually getting into `etcd` cluster?

For a example, can I do a health curl (using `ssh`) to `etcd` endpoints or see endpoints and get the return status **from the kubernetes master node? (i.e. without really getting inside the `etcd` master)**

Answer (score 1):

it really depends on how you configured the cluster. Actually, etcd cluster could work outside of k8s cluster at all. Also etcd could be configurred with TLS auth, so you will need to provide cert files to be able make any request via curl. `etcdctl` does everything you need. Something like:

```
~# export ETCDCTL_API=3
~# export ETCDCTL_ENDPOINTS=https://kub01.msk.test.ru:2379,https://kub02.msk.test.ru:2379,https://kub03.msk.test.ru:2379
~# etcdctl endpoint status
https://kub01.msk.test.ru:2379, e9bc9d307c96fd08, 3.3.13, 10 MB, true, 1745, 17368976
https://kub02.msk.test.ru:2379, 885ed66440d63a79, 3.3.13, 10 MB, false, 1745, 17368976
https://kub03.msk.test.ru:2379, 8c5c20ece034a652, 3.3.13, 10 MB, false, 1745, 17368976
```

or with the TLS:

```
~# etcdctl endpoint health
client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: remote error: tls: bad certificate
; error #1: remote error: tls: bad certificate
; error #2: remote error: tls: bad certificate

# need to export environment vars

~# export ETCDCTL_CACERT=<PATH_TO_FILE>
~# export ETCDCTL_CERT=<PATH_TO_FILE>
~# export ETCDCTL_KEY=<PATH_TO_FILE>
~# etcdctl endpoint health
https://kub01.msk.test.ru:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal: took = 2.946423ms
https://kub02.msk.test.ru:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal: took = 1.5883ms
https://kub03.msk.test.ru:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal: took = 1.745591ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the commands into a pod without actually getting inside the pod for example if I have to run `ls -l` inside the `etcd` pod, what I would is

```
kubectl exec -it -n kube-system etcd-kanister-control-plane -- ls -l
```

Similarly you can run any command instead of `ls -l`

Comment: ...which only works if you're running etcd inside your cluster instead of as a separate cluster